# Iterate an API call for until the end is found

Tags: javascript, iteration

I have an API where it returns limited results of data
the limit value cannot be greater than 1000

```
> https://api.source.com?start=0&limit=1000 //first call
> https://api.source.com?start=1001&limit=1000 //second call
> https://api.source.com?start=2001&limit=1000 //third call
> https://api.source.com?start=3001&limit=1000 //fourth call

{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Verticals Returned",
  "response": {
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 1000,
    "returned": 1000,
    "total": 3230,
    "data": [
      {
        "verticalID": 3,
        "verticalName": "Galaxies",
        "status": "Active",
        "groupID": 1,
        "createdOn": "2022-03-15 05:30:06",
        "groupName": "Solar",
        "totalOffers": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do it iterate this using a loop? while or any other loop is also fine.

I have tried with

```
limit =1000
start = 0;
total = undefined;
for(i=start;;i+=returned)
{
    y = call("https://api.source.com?start="+start+"&limit="+limit)
    total = y.total
    start = y.start
    returned = y.returned
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried with that code? Did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const apiLoop = async () =>{
   let counter = 0;
   const limit = 1000;
   while (true) {
       try{
          let y = await call("https://api.source.com?start="+(counter*limit)+"&limit="+limit);

          if(y==null)  
              break;

          counter++;
       }
       catch(e){
          console.log(e.message);
          break;
       }
   }
}

apiLoop();
```

Depending on what value `y` variable gets, when `start` query parameter is more than total length, the condition of breaking the **loop** will be different. Here I assume that `y` should be `null`.
Note that `call` function should be `async` and awaited in this code block. Because each `API` call in the iteration should get the result first and then based on the result, the function decides, whether to continue the `while` loop or not.